# deeplearning4j Expected model class name Model (found Functional)

Tags: java, spring, tensorflow, keras, deeplearning4j

deeplearning4j returning "Expected model class name Model (found Functional)." when trying to load a keras model.
same happens when  try to load it as sequential.

python :

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
model.save("resnet50.h5")
```

java(spring)

```
public INDArray useModel(String name, Long id) throws Exception{
    File file= new File("src/main/uploads/image.jpg");
    String resnet = "src/main/uploads/model/resnet50.h5";
    ComputationGraph model = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(resnet);
    NativeImageLoader loader = new NativeImageLoader(224, 224, 3);
    INDArray image = loader.asMatrix(file);
    INDArray[] output = model.output(image);
    return output[0];

}
```

mavn deps :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-modelimport</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
        <artifactId>datavec-data-image</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    </dependency>
```

any help fixing the problem or guidence to another library would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I tried to load my model either functional or sequentiel using DPL4J.

I solved the problem by downgrading tensorflow on python and re-train my model.
Then I used the loaded the file on Java.